# Build array from other array and table of values (Python)

Tags: arrays, performance, python-2.7, numpy

I have a table of values stored into a list of lists like:

```
A = [   [a[1],b[1],c[1]],
        [a[2],b[2],c[2]],
        ...

        [a[m],b[m],c[m]]]

with
a[i] < b[1]
b[i] < a[i+1]
0 < c[i] < 1
```

and a numpy array such as:

```
 X = [x[1], x[2], ..., x[n]]
```

I need to create an array

```
 Y = [y[1], y[2], ..., y[n]]
```

where each value of Y will correspond to

```
for i in [1,2, ..., n]:
  for k in [1,2, ..., m]:
     if a[k] <  x[i] < b[k]:
         y[i] = c[k]
     else:
         y[i] = 1
```

Please note that X and Y have the same length, but A is totally different. Y can take any value in the third column of A (c[k] for k= 1,2,... m), as long as a[k] <  x[i] < b[k] is met (for k= 1,2,... m and for i= 1,2,... n).

In the actual cases I am working on, n = 6789 and m = 6172.

I could do the verification using nested "for" cycles, but it is really slow. What is the fastest way to accomplish this? what if X and Y where 2D numpy arrays?

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
b = [11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91]
c = [ 0.917,  0.572,  0.993 ,  0.131,  0.44, 0.252 ,  0.005,  0.375,  0.341]

A = A = [[d,e,f] for d,e,f in zip(a,b,c)]

X = [1, 4, 10.2, 20.5, 25, 32, 41.3, 50.5, 73]
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS:**

```
Y = [1, 1, 0.993, 0.132, 1, 1, 1, 0.375, 1 ]
```

Comment: Why would you do `zip([1,2, ..., n],[1,2, ..., m])`? It seems likely that that doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @user2357112: you are indeed correct, I have updated the question. thanks.

Comment: The new version still looks wrong. Each `y[i]` value gets overwritten over and over.

Comment: @user2357112: yes, true, I had the order of the cycles swapped, sorry.

Comment: As user2357112 has already mentioned, `y[i]` get overwritten with the innermost nested loop. So, can you post same input data and show us the expected output to clear out the confusion? Also, what are the datasizes, i.e. n and m for your actual inputs?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Sample" input data and expected output for it to clear out confusion(s).

Comment: @Divakar Added sample data and data sizes to question as requested.

Comment: @jorgehumberto Would the [`posted solution`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30584042/3293881) work for you?

Comment: @Divakar: I am sorry, I have been unable to spend enough time in front of a computer in the last couple of days. I have not been able to test it yet with the real sample, but tested it with smaller ones and Approach #2 works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @jorgehumberto Let me know when you get a chance on how the approach #2 performs for the actual data?

Comment: @Divakar: Perfect, thanks! took 3.5 s to create the array (when expanded X and Y to a 2D array), instead of the few minutes it would take when I iterated over all elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1:** Using brute-force comparison with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
import numpy as np

# Convert to numpy arrays
A_arr = np.array(A)
X_arr = np.array(X)

# Mask that represents "if a[k] <  x[i] < b[k]:" for all i,k
mask = (A_arr[:,None,0]<X_arr) & (X_arr<A_arr[:,None,1])

# Get indices where the mask has 1s, i.e. the conditionals were satisfied
_,C = np.where(mask)

# Setup output numpy array and set values in it from third column of A 
# that has conditionals satisfied for specific indices
Y = np.ones_like(X_arr)
Y[C] = A_arr[C,2]
```

**Approach #2:** Based on binning with [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
import numpy as np

# Convert A to 2D numpy array
A_arr = np.asarray(A)

# Setup intervals for binning later on 
intv = A_arr[:,:2].ravel()

# Perform binning & get interval & grouped indices for each X 
intv_idx = np.searchsorted(intv, X, side='right')
grp_intv_idx = np.floor(intv_idx/2).astype(int)

# Get mask of valid indices, i.e. X elements are within grouped intervals
mask = np.fmod(intv_idx,2)==1

# Setup output array 
Y = np.ones(len(X))

# Extract col-3 elements with grouped indices and valid ones from mask
Y[mask] = A_arr[:,2][grp_intv_idx[mask]]

# Remove (set to 1's) elements that fall exactly on bin boundaries
Y[np.in1d(X,intv)] = 1
```

Please note that if you need the output as a list, you can convert the numpy array to a list with a call like this - `Y.tolist()`.

---

Sample run -

```
In [480]: A
Out[480]: 
[[139.0, 355.0, 0.5047342078960846],
 [419.0, 476.0, 0.3593886192040009],
 [580.0, 733.0, 0.3137694021600973]]

In [481]: X
Out[481]: [555, 689, 387, 617, 151, 149, 452]

In [482]: Y
Out[482]: 
array([ 1.        ,  0.3137694 ,  1.        ,  0.3137694 ,  0.50473421,
        0.50473421,  0.35938862])
```

Answer (score 0):

With 1-d arrays, it's not too bad:

```
a,b,c = np.array(A).T
mask = (a<x) & (x<b)
y = np.ones_like(x)
y[mask] = c[mask]
```

If `x` and `y` are higher-dimensional, then your `A` matrix will also need to be bigger. The basic concept works the same, though.

Comment: I am sorry, you made me realize that explanation was incorrect. A has length "m", but X and Y have length "n". Y can take any value in the third "column" of A. I have updated the question to make it clearer.